# How to calculate/determine Folder Size in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating application in Winform which among other things will also need to have the ability to calculate size of the folder.

Can someone give me pointers how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the following extension method to do that:

```
    public static long Size(this DirectoryInfo Directory, bool Recursive = false)
    {
        if (Directory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Directory");
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles("*", Recursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Sum(x => x.Length);
    }
```

Comment: This give the minimum disk space.   Doesn't account for block size and doesn't account for the space used by the directories themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to recursively enumerate the files in the folder and sum the file sizes. Remember to include system and hidden files for the correct size.

Here is a simple version:

```
long GetFolderSize(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    return files.Sum(fi => fi.Length);
}
```

Remember that a file may take up more space on the disk than it's Length, since a file always takes up a whole number of blocks on the file system (in case that matters to your application).

Answer (score 2):

You need to obtain all files from your directory (including subdirectories) and in the sum loop their size. Example:

```
static long GetDirectorySize(string path)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    long size = 0;
    foreach (string name in files)
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
        size += info.Length;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't include subdirectories.